# Programmatically rotate drawable or view

Tags: java, android, rotation

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="360" />
```

I want programmatically rotate the drawable.

How should I do that?

Here is my callback

```
private class RotateListener implements RotateGestureDetector.OnRotateGestureListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onRotate(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
            double deltaAngle) {

        return true;
    }
}
```

The `deltaangle` not more than 0.1, I not sure what is the extract value.