# How to rotate imageview to clockwise by 10degree on every time button is clicked

Tags: android, imageview

I have an image view and a button, what I want when I click the button I want to rotate the image view by 10 degrees. Please help me out.

Below is the code I have used

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator">
<rotate android:fromDegrees="360"
    android:toDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="0"
    android:duration="5000" />
```

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator">
<rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="10"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:duration="1500" />
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083811/programmatically-rotate-drawable-or-view

Answer (score 0):

```
view.animate().rotation(10).start();
```